# Number of partitions of the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}>0$. 
For example $$P(4) = \{(4),(3,1),(2,2),(2,1,1),(3,1,1,1)  \}.$$
Define a set, $$\mathcal{P} :=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}} P(n)$$

My question: is $\mathcal{P}$ countable?

Comment: Note that $\mathcal P$ is not the set of *all* partitions of natural numbers, but only the set of those with finite support. So the naming of this set is quite misleading.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I've edited the question to make it less misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for each $n$, $P(n)$ is finite. What do you know about a countable union of finite sets?

Comment: Just a note: In this case we don't even need any form of choice in order to conclude that $\mathcal P$ is countable. We can just write down a surjection $\mathbb N \to P$ without relying on this general result.